# Lubuntu doesn't fully poweroff or reboot

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, shutdown

I'm really new to Linux so forgive my ignorance. I did a fresh install of Lubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on my pc and everything went smoothly. I didn't install any other software after this install nor changed anyting in terms of configurations or similar stuff. My system would just shutdown and reboot just fine. This morning I was propmted to upgrade my system and did a full upgrade, which was successful and then I restarted my pc. After this upgrade though, my machine doesn't want to reboot or shutdown completely. The screen would go blank but fans are still on and so is the power led. Hence, I have to perform a hard reset by holding the power button. Since I didn't do anything after I installed my OS, I highly suspect it is a bug related to the full upgrade I applied. It's really frustrating, does anyone have the same issue than me and know how to fix it?
Thanks in advance for your patience and understanding, I wish you all a happy new year!

Comment: If you boot the *live* media from which you installed, does it shutdown from there? (from your description I'd say yes, ie. it shutdown correctly until you applied newer (*likely*) kernel upgrades). One option which may help is switch to the GA kernel stack (default for installs with 20.04 & 20.04.1 media, but not 20.04.2 or later).  To see how you can read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and search for "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:*" (in the 20.04 discussion).  You don't need to remove the HWE stack as you can have both installed & select at boot which you'll use

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! So, basically the affected kernel version is 5.11.0-43-generic while the one that works for me is 5.11.0-27-generic. Version 5.4.0-91-generic is not affected by the issue I reported but there are issues with network drivers I guess, since I can't see nor connect to wifi networks. Is there a way to set version 5.11.0.27 as default without having to interact with Grub? Also, do you think a patch will be introduced to fix this issue with the most recent version?

Comment: You can change `grub` to boot a specific OS/kernel; but you'll want to put a (`apt-mark`) *hold* on the kernel that works; so it's not removed in due course as newer kernels are installed; the 5.11 kernel will be EOL soon as it'll get replaced by 5.13 (at 20.04.4), where as 5.4 will remain *stable* & patched for security fixes the life of the product (why I suggest GA kernel stack). Kernel *devs* can't know about the issue (function that no longer works is called *regression*) until filed via bug report; so fixes can't be worked on until then (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: Ok thanks. Let's say I want to stick with 5.4 (I fixed missing drivers) and purge the other two versions (5.11.0-43 and 5.11.0-27). Will my 5.4 kernel overwritten and upgraded again to version 5.11 when performing a full upgrade, unless I put an apt-mark hold on it? Thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: You can have the GA kernels installed (ie. the 5.4) & HWE (5.8, 5.11, 5.13 etc) installed as well; as each upgrade they'll replace older kernels (ie. later 5.4's will replace earlier 5.4's, newer 5.11's will replace older 5.11's with 5.13's replacing 5.11's when your 20.04.3 upgrades to 20.04.4 etc... so the 5.4 (GA) kernels & HWE kernels (5.8 & later) are treated separately (*installed by different packages so treated separately*). ie. HWE newer kernels will only replace older HWE, not the GA (5.4) kernels etc - why `apt-mark hold <package>` is useful to hold a specific package version.

Comment: Got you! Thank you very much, you saved my day! I'm also going to file a bug report against that specific kernel version.